# How to use a UTF-8 string as a filename in a multipart/form-data POST request (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, utf-8

I am trying to send a file named “pestaña2” using requests.

```
files = { 'f': ('pestaña2.png', open('/Users . . . Definition/' + HeadWrd + '.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')}
```

But the request fails to upload the file and I get the response

```
message=You must pass a file in as f.
```

The file name appears in the request as follows:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="f"; filename*=utf-8''pesta%C3%B1a2.png
```

If I remove the “ñ” character from the filename, the issue goes away, so I know that the issue is with the special character. If I upload the image manually there is no problem and the filename appears in the request as “filename=pestaña2.png.”
Is there some way I can ensure that special characters are passed along properly?

Comment: Does the service you are posting to actually *support* such filenames?

Comment: Well, as I said above, uploading the file manually works fine and the character then appears as expected. But if there is some way I can encode the filename so that the file can be uploaded that would be more than satisfactory.

Comment: I went through the source code of requests and urllib3. As far as I can say, `requests` uses `urllib3.fields.RequestField` to create a multipart form which says 'Field names and filenames must be unicode'. I also searched entire `requests` and `urllib3` source to find an exception like "You must pass".. but couldn't find any.  We need more debug information to solve this.

Comment: Right, so there should not be any problem passing it through requests. What information would be helpful?

Comment: The entire traceback stack for starters. Also you need to tag us so that we get notified. Tagging him on your behalf. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Server can't improve file name, client "call name" is file name. Or need push as object not a file.

Comment: @MiteshNinja You mean like error messages? The code runs and exits as though there is no problem (Process finished with exit code 0), but looking at the response in Fiddler4 I see that the request fails to upload the image. Pardon my ignorance if that is not what you mean. I have very little experience with Python. How do I get the traceback?